# How to convert flat hash into nested after conditional key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash

I'm trying to convert xml into json structure. I got all rows, extract first as header and zip it with all next rows, but I have to nest keys after word attribute, how to do it?

current steps:

vars:

```
header = ["id",
 "groupName",
 "words",
 "Unit",
 "Name",
 "Image"]

rows = [["1",
  "gr 1",
  nil,
  "1",
  "Test",
  "test.png"],
 ["1",
  "gr 1",
  nil,
  "23",
  "Taefawe",
  "adf.png"]]
```

current output =>

```
[{"id"=>"1",
  "groupName"=>"Unit 1",
  "words"=>nil,
  "Unit"=>"1",
  "Name"=>"Test",
  "Image"=>"test.png"},
 {"id"=>"1",
  "groupName"=>"gr 1",
  "words"=>nil,
  "Unit"=>"23",
  "Name"=>"Taefawe",
  "Image"=>"adf.png"}]
```

desired:

```
[{"id"=>"1",
  "groupName"=>"Unit 1",
  "words"=>{
    "Unit"=>"1",
    "Name"=>"Test",
    "Image"=>"test.png"
  }
 },
 {"id"=>"1",
  "groupName"=>"gr 1",
  "words"=> {
    "Unit"=>"23",
    "Name"=>"Taefawe",
    "Image"=>"adf.png"
  }}]
```

current code:

```
rows = doc.sheets.first.rows
header = rows.shift

out = []
rows.each do |row|
  out << Hash[header.zip(row.map{|val| val})]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your headers is always constant, the best way it seemed to me is:

```
rows.inject([]) do |res, row|
  res << {"id" => row[0],
          "groupName" => row[1],
          "words" => {
                        "Unit" => row[3],
                        "Name"  => row[4],
                        "Image" => row[5]} 
         }
end
```

or you can replace the `key` constants in the `hash` with `header[index]` as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting it back as true xml you should be able to just use:

```
Hash.from_xml(doc.sheets)
```